# How would I integrate this function numerically

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

I would like to integrate the following function numerically, but I'm getting a bit confused how to set it up correctly, could someone give me a hint in the right direction

$$ y(t) = f(t)e^{-\nu t} + \int_0^t{f(\tau)e^{-\nu t}y(t-\tau)d\tau}$$

So I wasn't really sure where to begin, I started doing the following to set up the equations for finding $y(t+\Delta t)$ :

$$ y(t+\Delta t) = f(t+\Delta t)e^{-\nu (t+\Delta t)} + \int_0^{t+\Delta t}{f(\tau)e^{-\nu t}y(t+\Delta t-\tau)d\tau}$$

$$ = f(t+\Delta t)e^{-\nu (t+\Delta T)} + \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}{f(\tau)e^{-\nu t}y(t+\Delta t-\tau)d\tau} + \int_0^{t}{f(\tau)e^{-\nu t}y(t-\tau)d\tau}$$

where I can use the relation $\int_0^{t}{f(\tau)e^{-\nu t}y(t-\tau)d\tau} = y(t) - f(t)e^{-vt}$ to rewrite this as

$$y(t+\Delta t) = y(t) - f(t)e^{-vt} + f(t+\Delta t)e^{-\nu (t+\Delta t)} + \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}{f(\tau)e^{-\nu t}y(t+\Delta t-\tau)d\tau}$$

If we know $y(t)$ am I right in saying this can be solved by assuming that the integrands are constant over the interval $\Delta t$, so

$$y(t+\Delta t) = y(t) - f(t)e^{-vt} + f(t+\Delta t)e^{-\nu (t+\Delta t)} + \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}{f(\tau)e^{-\nu t}y(t+\Delta t-\tau)d\tau}$$

$$= y(t) - f(t)e^{-vt} + f(t+\Delta t)e^{-\nu (t+\Delta t)} - \frac{1}{\nu}\bigg[{f(\tau)e^{-\nu t}y(t+\Delta t-\tau)d\tau}\bigg]_t^{t+\Delta t}$$

Is this right so far? I'm trying to compare with an implementation and it doesn't quite look the same...

Comment: If you differentiate your first line, by using the fundamental theorem of calculus, you will get an ODE (actually, a delayed one), which can be solved numerically. Then you could solve numerically that equation, but I'm not sure if that is feasible for you. It's just an idea